# How to set up system wide proxy in Kali Linux?

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, proxy

I am living in a hostel where we get access to internet through LAN ports by connecting to a proxy server. I am running Kali Linux in Oracle VirtualBox and that's where I need internet access.

Here is what is did:

1. I have changed my network settings in VirtualBox to Bridged Adapter
2. I checked that the Bridged adapter was working by setting up a proxy connection in Firefox's network setting within the VM (Firefox > Settings > Network Settings > Settings). It was working and I could connect to the internet.
3. I then reset the network settings because I wanted the proxy setting to be system wide, not just limited to Firefox.
4. I then tried to set up a proxy connection in Kali Linux by [editing the "bash.bashrc" file in "/etc"](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/feature/How-to-configure-and-customize-Kali-Linux). I basically appended the following to the end of the file "bash.bashrc" in "/etc". The IP address here is obviously an example.

> export http_proxy="http://999.99.999.99:8080"

> export https_proxy="https://999.99.999.99:8080"

This failed to work, and I cannot connect to internet in the VM.

Can anyone tell me what should I do to set up a system wide proxy?

Comment: Define "Failed to work". Don't just include a link; link rot is a significant problem. Tell us exactly what you did, what you hoped the outcome would be, and what didn't happen.

Comment: I can think of three or four reasons why what you may have done didn't have the desired outcome, but they all depend on what exactly you did and didn't do.

Comment: @Shadur I have edited the question a bit. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Only somewhat. Define "Failed to connect to the internet". I'm *assuming* you mean that your web browser still isn't showing you the sites you want, but how did you start your web browser?

Comment: @Shadur I don't understand. Firefox comes pre-installed in Kali Linux and it allows to set up proxy settings just for it, which I used to check if the Bridged Adapter was working. It was working and I could connect to internet through the browser, but I want to access internet through terminal too. So I reset the Firefox proxy settings and am trying to set up a system wide proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some clarifications I think I see what's going on.

Changes in `/etc/bash.bashrc` are not automagically loaded until the next time you log in, and even then they're only loaded for that particular login session.

If you've got a graphical shell going, and then use an editor or a terminal to alter `/etc/bash.bashrc` to add those proxy variables, they won't be visible to your shell until the next time you launch the entire shell. So you'll need to log out completely and log back in.

You should then also be able to verify whether they were loaded by opening a terminal window and typing `echo $http_proxy`

Comment: "echo $http_proxy" shows the proxy IP, but I still cannot connect to internet.

Comment: Please, **please** for my sanity's sake stop conflating "use my web browser" and "connect to the internet". Have you logged out of your entire desktop session and logged back in? Possibly even rebooted your system?

Comment: Yes, I did all of those.

Comment: Test your setup by using - for instance - `wget http://www.google.com/`  and see if it gets a response. If it does, at least your environment variables are recognized and the problem lies with firefox not honoring them.

Comment: I think it connected. It says : " Connecting to 172.16.199.40:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html" and then 'index.html' saved.

Comment: Congratulations, your systemwide proxy works, it's just that firefox doesn't actually look for that variable or otherwise doesn't get it read.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you advice anything about the issue with Firefox?

Comment: One longshot would be to us `ps axuf  | grep firefox` to check for the PIDs of firefox processes, then check `/proc/<pid>/environ` of one of them to see if it even contains `http_proxy`. If it does, then firefox simply doesn't honor the setting. If it doesn't, then your graphical shell doesn't load `bash.bashrc` during startup.

Comment: Well, it says "permission denied" when I run  `/proc/<pid>/environ`

Comment: That's because that's not an executable, it's a file. You read it with an editor or with `cat` or `grep`